# Populate NaN cells in dataframe table based on reference table based on specific row(s) and column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup, fillna

I have two tables.  The first reference table is below:

```
| Name | Target  | Bonus |
|------|--------:|------:|
| Joe  |      40 |    46 |
| Phil |      38 |    42 |
| Dean |      65 |    70 |
```

The Python code to generate the table is:

```
# Data for the table
data = {
    'Name': ['Joe', 'Phil', 'Dean'],
    'Target': [40, 38, 65],
    'Bonus': [46, 42, 70]
}

# Creating the DataFrame
ref = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My second table is below:

```
| week       | Metrics | Joe | Dean |
|------------|---------|----:|-----:|
| 11/6/2023  | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/6/2023  | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/6/2023  | Score   |  33 |   71 |
| 11/13/2023 | Target  |  40 |  NaN |
| 11/13/2023 | Bonus   |  46 |  NaN |
| 11/13/2023 | Score   |  45 |  NaN |
| 11/20/2023 | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/20/2023 | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/20/2023 | Score   |  35 |   68 |
| 11/27/2023 | Target  | NaN |   65 |
| 11/27/2023 | Bonus   | NaN |   70 |
| 11/27/2023 | Score   | NaN |   44 |
| 12/4/2023  | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 12/4/2023  | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 12/4/2023  | Score   |  42 |   66 |
```

The Python code to generate this table is:

```
# Data for the new table
data = {
    'week': ['11/6/2023', '11/6/2023', '11/6/2023', '11/13/2023', '11/13/2023', '11/13/2023',
             '11/20/2023', '11/20/2023', '11/20/2023', '11/27/2023', '11/27/2023', '11/27/2023',
             '12/4/2023', '12/4/2023', '12/4/2023'],
    'Metrics': ['Target', 'Bonus', 'Score', 'Target', 'Bonus', 'Score',
                'Target', 'Bonus', 'Score', 'Target', 'Bonus', 'Score',
                'Target', 'Bonus', 'Score'],
    'Joe': [40, 46, 33, 40, 46, 45, 40, 46, 35, None, None, None, 40, 46, 42],
    'Dean': [65, 70, 71, None, None, None, 65, 70, 68, 65, 70, 44, 65, 70, 66]
}

# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As you can see Dean has a week where his Target, Bonus, and Score cells are blank.  So does Joe in a later week.  In these specific instances where the cell is NaN I want to populate them using the following rules:

- Get Target and Bonus cell values for each person from the first reference table and populate the NaN cell accordingly.
- Set the Score cell equal to the Target cell value for the person.

My desired output table would look like this:

```
| week       | Metrics | Joe | Dean |
|------------|---------|----:|-----:|
| 11/6/2023  | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/6/2023  | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/6/2023  | Score   |  33 |   71 |
| 11/13/2023 | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/13/2023 | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/13/2023 | Score   |  45 |   65 |
| 11/20/2023 | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/20/2023 | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/20/2023 | Score   |  35 |   68 |
| 11/27/2023 | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 11/27/2023 | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 11/27/2023 | Score   |  40 |   44 |
| 12/4/2023  | Target  |  40 |   65 |
| 12/4/2023  | Bonus   |  46 |   70 |
| 12/4/2023  | Score   |  42 |   66 |
```

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? You added the [fillna] tag, so I assume you know how to use the `.fillna` method, but do you know how to reshape the data accordingly? It could help to post your best attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only one block of NaN per column at most**

Another possible solution, which loops through the `df` columns corresponding to each person and, for each block of `NaN` (identified by `loc`), assigns the corresponding block of values in `ref` (also identified by `loc`):

```
names = ['Joe', 'Dean']

d = ref.assign(Score = ref['Target'])

for x in names:
    df.loc[df[x].isna(), x] = d.loc[d['Name'].eq(x), 'Target':'Score'].T.values
```

**General case**

In case there is more than a single block of `NaN` per person, we need to change the code slightly:

```
names = ['Joe', 'Dean']

d = ref.assign(Score = ref['Target'])

for x in names:
    n_blocks = df[x].isna().sum() // 3
    df.loc[df[x].isna(), x] = np.tile(d.loc[d['Name'].eq(x), 'Target':'Score']
                                      .values.flatten(), n_blocks)
```

**Edit**

To satisfy the new requirement of the OP: Instead of order Target, Bonus and Score, it is needed the order Bonus, Target and Score. In such a case, we need to readjust the previous code:

```
names = ['Joe', 'Dean']

d = ref.assign(Score = ref['Target'])
d = d[['Name', 'Bonus', 'Target', 'Score']]

for x in names:
    n_blocks = df[x].isna().sum() // 3
    df.loc[df[x].isna(), x] = np.tile(d.loc[d['Name'].eq(x), 'Bonus':'Score']
                                      .values.flatten(), n_blocks)
```

Output:

```
          week Metrics   Joe  Dean
0    11/6/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
1    11/6/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
2    11/6/2023   Score  33.0  71.0
3   11/13/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
4   11/13/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
5   11/13/2023   Score  45.0  65.0
6   11/20/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
7   11/20/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
8   11/20/2023   Score  35.0  68.0
9   11/27/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
10  11/27/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
11  11/27/2023   Score  40.0  44.0
12   12/4/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
13   12/4/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
14   12/4/2023   Score  42.0  66.0
```

Comment: PaulS: thank you so much for the code!

I just realized something though.  My first reference table's columns are in the wrong order.  It should be Bonus first then Target.  When I do that reorder, your code breaks.  

Do you have any suggestions?  Thx

Comment: It is easy to make my code working under a new order. But what would the new order be? Bonus, Target and Score, @PineNuts0?

Comment: Thanks, @PaulS!  It should be Bonus, Target, then Score.  I'll buy you a coffee via your profile link for your help on this.  Really appreciate it!

And there will be cases where there could be multiple blocks of NaN per Name column.

Comment: Done, I think. Please, see above, in my answer, the solution for the new order, @PineNuts0. Good luck!

Comment: The Score should still be the Target and not the Bonus.

Comment: Does the column `metrics` of `df` change? Or is the same?

Comment: Clarification question: what is this snippet of code doing? 'Target Score, Bonus':'wtd_pt_touches_final'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256354/discussion-between-pinenuts0-and-pauls).

Comment: My code snippet is assuming that the column `Metrics` has the following sequence: Bonus, Target and Score. The corresponding values are filling the `NaN`accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the name of second data frame to df2, since we cannot them have the same name:

```
# Iterate over each row in df2
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    # For each person
    for person in ['Joe', 'Dean']:
        # If the value is NaN
        if pd.isnull(row[person]):
            # If the metric is 'Score', use the 'Target' value
            if row['Metrics'] == 'Score':
                value = df.loc[df['Name'] == person, 'Target'].values[0]
            # Otherwise, check if the metric exists in df and use its value
            elif row['Metrics'] in df.columns:
                value = df.loc[df['Name'] == person, row['Metrics']].values[0]
            else:
                continue  # Skip if the metric is not in df and is not 'Score'
            # Replace the NaN value in df2
            df2.at[i, person] = value
```

This should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['Joe', 'Phil', 'Dean'],
        'Target': [40, 38, 65],
        'Bonus': [46, 42, 70]
    })
data["Score"] = data["Target"]
transposed = data.set_index('Name').transpose().rename(columns=data['Name'].to_dict())
#
Name    Joe  Phil  Dean
Target   40    38    65
Bonus    46    42    70
Score    40    38    65
#

data2 = data2.merge(transposed[["Joe","Dean"]], how="left", right_index=True, left_on="Metrics", suffixes=("","_filler"))
data2["Joe"] = data2["Joe"].fillna(data2["Joe_filler"])
data2["Dean"] = data2["Dean"].fillna(data2["Dean_filler"])
data2.drop(columns=["Joe_filler","Dean_filler"])
#
          week Metrics   Joe  Dean  Joe_filler  Dean_filler
0    11/6/2023  Target  40.0  65.0          40           65
1    11/6/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0          46           70
2    11/6/2023   Score  33.0  71.0          40           65
3   11/13/2023  Target  40.0  65.0          40           65
4   11/13/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0          46           70
5   11/13/2023   Score  45.0  65.0          40           65
6   11/20/2023  Target  40.0  65.0          40           65
7   11/20/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0          46           70
8   11/20/2023   Score  35.0  68.0          40           65
9   11/27/2023  Target  40.0  65.0          40           65
10  11/27/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0          46           70
11  11/27/2023   Score  40.0  44.0          40           65
12   12/4/2023  Target  40.0  65.0          40           65
13   12/4/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0          46           70
14   12/4/2023   Score  42.0  66.0          40           65
```

I kept the last two columns (didnt drop inplace) so you can see whats happening with those left merges and how the fillna works.

There should be a cleaner solution and a more compact one, but as an inspiration this could be useful for you.

```
# solution 2
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Joe', 'Phil', 'Dean'],
    'Target': [40, 38, 65],
    'Bonus': [46, 42, 70]
})
data["Score"] = data["Target"]

transposed = data.set_index('Name').transpose().rename(columns=data['Name'].to_dict())
data2["Joe"] = np.where(data2["Joe"].isna(), data2["Metrics"].map(transposed["Joe"].to_dict()),data2["Joe"])
data2["Dean"] = np.where(data2["Dean"].isna(), data2["Metrics"].map(transposed["Dean"].to_dict()),data2["Dean"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

##### 1. Create a reference map from 'ref':

```
ref['Score'] = ref['Target']
ref.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
ref_map = ref.to_dict('index')
print(ref_map)
>>>
{'Joe': {'Target': 40, 'Bonus': 46, 'Score': 40},
 'Phil': {'Target': 38, 'Bonus': 42, 'Score': 38},
 'Dean': {'Target': 65, 'Bonus': 70, 'Score': 65}}
```

##### 2. Fill the 'Metrics' for each specified person's column in DataFrame 'df'

```
columns_to_fill = ['Joe', 'Dean']

df[columns_to_fill] = df[columns_to_fill].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(df['Metrics']))
print(df)
>>>
          week Metrics     Joe    Dean
0    11/6/2023  Target    40.0    65.0
1    11/6/2023   Bonus    46.0    70.0
2    11/6/2023   Score    33.0    71.0
3   11/13/2023  Target    40.0  Target
4   11/13/2023   Bonus    46.0   Bonus
5   11/13/2023   Score    45.0   Score
6   11/20/2023  Target    40.0    65.0
7   11/20/2023   Bonus    46.0    70.0
8   11/20/2023   Score    35.0    68.0
9   11/27/2023  Target  Target    65.0
10  11/27/2023   Bonus   Bonus    70.0
11  11/27/2023   Score   Score    44.0
12   12/4/2023  Target    40.0    65.0
13   12/4/2023   Bonus    46.0    70.0
14   12/4/2023   Score    42.0    66.0
```

##### 3. Replace values in 'df' using the reference map 'ref_map'

```
result = df.replace(ref_map)
print(result)
>>>
          week Metrics   Joe  Dean
0    11/6/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
1    11/6/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
2    11/6/2023   Score  33.0  71.0
3   11/13/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
4   11/13/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
5   11/13/2023   Score  45.0  65.0
6   11/20/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
7   11/20/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
8   11/20/2023   Score  35.0  68.0
9   11/27/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
10  11/27/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
11  11/27/2023   Score  40.0  44.0
12   12/4/2023  Target  40.0  65.0
13   12/4/2023   Bonus  46.0  70.0
14   12/4/2023   Score  42.0  66.0
```